# How to calculate Future Value (FV) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, finance

I've been given a task to convert a simple spreadsheet to a HTML form to be used on a website, that is going to do some calculations using JavaScript. This would be no problem at all except I know *nothing* about financial functions, and I've ran into FV (Future Value).

This is the spreadsheet:

```
B3 = 100
B4 = 10
B5 = B4*12
B6 = 12
B7 = 3
B8 = (1+B6)^(1/12)-1
B9 = ABS(FV(B8,B5,B3/(1+B7),,1)) // and here lies the problem
```

This is what OO.org's help has to say about FV:

> Returns the future value of an investment based on periodic, constant payments and a constant interest rate (Future Value).
>
> Syntax: FV(Rate; Num_periods; Payment; PV (optional); Type)

**The question is: How does one calculate FV using the parameters above?**

Sample values:

```
B3 = 100          1        1        2
B4 = 10           1        2        2
B9 = 21,751.06    12.39    26.28    52.55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future value is just the principal amount plus all the accrued interest over the period outstanding.

In your example, the principal is 100 (B3), the time is 10 years (120 months -- B5), and the interest rate is B8.  Are you sure that B6 does not equal .12, or 12%?  That would be an annual interest rate of 12%, or about 1% per month (the actual formula for the monthly interest rate that would yield a 12% annual rate is 1.12 ^ (1/12) - 1).

The future value is simply principal times (1 + interest rate) ^ time, or in this case, roughly 100*(1.01)^120.

Answer (score 16):

This is the exact FV formula from Excel in Javascript. It works with 0% interest as well

```
function FV(rate, nper, pmt, pv, type) {
  var pow = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper),
     fv;
  if (rate) {
   fv = (pmt*(1+rate*type)*(1-pow)/rate)-pv*pow;
  } else {
   fv = -1 * (pv + pmt * nper);
  }
  return fv.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: This function mimics the functionality of Excel's own FV function yet it is quite limited in it's functionality. Excel TVM functions including FV do not allow for more complex financial calculations. Take for example, the deposits are monthly in amount of $100 for 5 years yet the interest is compounded quarterly. There is no way in Excel FV function to calculate the future value of this annuity that makes 60 monthly deposits when interest is earned quarterly.

Comment: It's good to know. Can you modify it and make it to the way you wanted?

Comment: There is lot more to TVM functions than what is offered by Excel, iWork Numbers, OO Calc and other spreadsheet programs and financial calculators. To amend these functions one would have to replace the existing TVM equation upon which these 5 TVM functions are based and replace it with two different TVM equations that will allow for annuity payments with growing, shrinking, increasing and decreasing annuities. The actual code for this will require introduction of a new function called GRADIENT and other auxiliary functions to get the job done. tadXL add-in offered all that but its gone now

Answer (score -1):

Here's [a calculator](http://www.dkcpa.com/calc/java_fv1.html) that you can refer to.

Go to the Javascript source, you can find that the formula to calculate the future value is this:

```
function checkNumber(input, min, max, msg)

{

    msg = msg + " field has invalid data: " + input.value;



    var str = input.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        var ch = str.substring(i, i + 1)

        if ((ch < "0" || "9" < ch) && ch != '.') {

            alert(msg);

            return false;

        }

    }

    var num = 0 + str

    if (num < min || max < num) {

        alert(msg + " not in range [" + min + ".." + max + "]");

        return false;

    }

    input.value = str;

    return true;

}



function computeField(input)

{

    if (input.value != null && input.value.length != 0)

        input.value = "" + eval(input.value);

    computeForm(input.form);

}



function computeForm(form)

{

    if ((form.payments.value == null || form.payments.value.length == 0) ||

        (form.interest.value == null || form.interest.value.length == 0) ||

        (form.principal.value == null || form.principal.value.length == 0)) {

        return;

    }



    if (!checkNumber(form.payments, 1, 480, "# of payments") ||

        !checkNumber(form.interest, .001, 99, "Interest") ||

        !checkNumber(form.principal, 1, 10000000, "Principal")) {

        form.fv.value = "Invalid";

        return;

    }



    var i = form.interest.value;

    if (i > 1.0) {

        i = i / 100.0;

        form.interest.value = i;

    }

    i /= 12;


   var pow = form.principal.value;

    for (var j = 0; j < form.payments.value *12; j++)

        pow = (pow * i) + (pow *1);

    form.fv.value = pow

        form.totalint.value = (form.fv.value - form.principal.value)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You will have hard time moving Excel to web.
Instead you better consider using Google Docs.

But if you need only this one particular spreedsheet then [this page](http://www.freemathhelp.com/future-value.html) explains the formula.
Additionally you can find the information on the [Compound Interest Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Simplified_calculation).

Comment: +1 for forgetting about Javascript and using Google Apps instead.