# Why am I getting a different results to Excel with my FV calculation?

Tags: javascript, excel, finance

I'm trying to recreate Excel's Future Value (FV) calculation in JavaScript.

The formula I have in Excel is:

`=-FV(4.15/12,1,500,500,1)`

Which is:

`=-FV(Rate/12,No. Months,Payment per period,Starting amount,Payment Timing)`

This gives the desired result: `$1,003.46`

However, when I try to recreate this in JS:

```
   FV = function (rate, nper, pmt, pv, type) {
        var pow = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper),
           fv;
        if (rate) {
         fv = (pmt*(1+rate*type)*(1-pow)/rate)-pv*pow;
        } else {
         fv = -1 * (pv + pmt * nper);
        }
        return fv.toFixed(2);
      }

 var monthlyRate = 4.15 / 12;
 var test = FV(monthlyRate, 1, 500, 500, 1);
 console.log(test);
```

I get the result:

```
-1345.83
```

I'm not sure what's going on here and why this is different. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780645/how-to-calculate-future-value-fv-using-javascript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, but I've also googled other equations and theyre all similar

Comment: I put `=-FV(4.15/12,1,500,500,1)` into google sheets and it gave `1,345.83`

Comment: I just copy/pasted your formula `=-FV(4.15/12,1,500,500,1)` into Excel and it returns `$1,345.83`  However, if you instead use `=-FV(4.15%/12,1,500,500,1)` you will get `$1,003.46`  Note the `%` sign. Perhaps in your JS code you should use `4.15/100`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't converting the rate from a percentage properly.

4.15% = 0.0415

So:

```
var monthlyRate = (4.15 / 100) / 12;
```